# How to stop a warning dialog from halting execution of a Python program that's controlling it?

Tags: python, win32gui

Using Win32GUI and [Watsup](http://www.tizmoi.net/watsup/intro.html), I'm writing a bit of Python code to automate a search across a database that is accessed through a program that doesn't come with an interface for it. As such, I can take a string from a list and then input it into the search box and press 'lookup'.

However, when the search returns more than 1000 results, the program throws a warning dialog --which is simply a notification of the number of results--which halts the execution of the Python code. I can't get the code to progress past the line where it presses lookup.

At a guess, this would be because it doesn't expect a window or know how to handle a warning--but I don't either, other than manually accepting it. Below is the relevent sample of code, though it's probably not very enlightening. After "clickButton(LookupButton)", the execution halts.

```
LookupButtonlocation = elemstring.find("Lookup", AuthNameFieldlocation) - 15

#Use Regex search to find handles
number_regex = re.compile(';(\d+);')
AuthNameEdit = int(number_regex.search(elemstring[AuthNameFieldlocation:]).group(1))
LookupButton = int(number_regex.search(elemstring[LookupButtonlocation:]).group(1))

#Input new Author into Edit Field
setEditText(AuthNameEdit, "John Campbell")
#Click lookup button
clickButton(LookupButton)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a WATSUP user, but I do something very similar using pywinauto - in my case I'm running a number of automated tests that open various 3rd party programs that, in a similar way, throw up inconvenient warning dialogs.  It's a bit difficult to deal with dialogs that you don't know about, however if you do know which dialogs appear, but not *when* they appear, you can start a thread to just deal with those pop-ups.  The following is a simple example from what I'm doing, and uses pywinauto but you could adapt the approach for WATSUP:

```
import time
import threading

class ClearPopupThread(threading.Thread): 
    def __init__(self, window_name, button_name, quit_event):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.quit_event = quit_event
        self.window_name = window_name
        self.button_name = button_name
    def run(self):
        from pywinauto import application, findwindows                
        while True:
            try:
                handles = findwindows.find_windows(title=self.window_name)
            except findwindows.WindowNotFoundError:
                pass #Just do nothing if the pop-up dialog was not found
            else: #The window was found, so click the button
                for hwnd in handles:
                    app = application.Application()
                    app.Connect(handle=hwnd)
                    popup = app[self.window_name]                    
                    button = getattr(popup, self.button_name)
                    button.Click()                    
            if self.quit_event.is_set():
                break            
            time.sleep(1) #should help reduce cpu load a little for this thread
```

Essentially this thread is just an infinite loop that looks for a pop-up window by name, and if it finds it, it clicks on a button to close the window.  If you have many pop-up windows you can open one thread per popup (bug that's not overly efficient, though).  Because it's an infinite loop, I have the thread looking to see if an event is set, to allow me to stop the thread from my main program.  So, in the main program I do something like this:

```
#Start the thread
quit_event = threading.Event()
mythread = ClearPopupThread('Window Popup Title', 'Yes button', quit_event)
# ...
# My program does it's thing here
# ...
# When my program is done I need to end the thread
quit_event.set()
```

This is not necessarily the only way to deal with your issue, but is a way that's worked for me.  Sorry I can't really help you much with dealing with WATSUP (I always found pywinauto a bit easier to use), but I noticed on the WATSUP homepage (http://www.tizmoi.net/watsup/intro.html), Example 2 does something similar without using threads, i.e., looks for a named window and clicks a specific button on that window.