# Pywinauto unable to find/close pop-up window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywinauto

**Source code**

```
def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False

if is_admin():
    app = Application(backend='uia').start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Advantech\\AdamApax.NET Utility\\Program\\AdamNET.exe")
    win = app['Advantech Adam/Apax .NET Utility (Win32) Version 2.05.11 (B19)']
    win.wait('ready')
    win.menu_select("Setup->Refresh Serial and Ethernet")
    win.top_window().print_control_identifiers(filename="file.txt")
    # win.top_window().OKButton.click_input()  ---------This is what I hope to do

else
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, __file__, None, 1)
```

**Problem Statement**

I had to run this application with elevation rights. The above is my code. The problem is I can't identify the window (view in ***output*** image) that pops up after selection from menu. I need to close the window. Please excuse the line

`win.top_window().print_control_identifiers(filename="file.txt")`

It was meant write the identifiers into a text file because the structure of this code does not display the outputs for me to view. However, since nothing is appended, I guess pywinauto couldn't identify the dialog.

For a clearer understanding, please view the image (input) of when it selects the menu.

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2jQO.png)

Now, it pops up with this dialog (output)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxi1S.png)

I've also used spy to identify the caption and it gives:

(**Handle:** 004E07D4, 
**Caption:** Information, 
**Class:** #32770(Dialog), 
**Style:** 94C801C5)

***Other things I've tried:***

Besides using `win.topwindow()`  to identify the dialog, I've used

```
win[Information].OKButton.click_input()
win[Information].OK.click_input()
win[Information].OK.close()
win[Information].OK.kill(soft=false)
win.Information.OKButton.click_input()
win.Information.OK.click_input()
win.Information.OK.close()
win.Information.OK.kill(soft=false)
app[Information] ...... curious if I could discover the new window from original application
```

I've also send keys like enter, space, esc & alt-f4 to close the dialog with libraries like keyboard, pynput & ctypes. It still doesn't work.

Link to download the same application: http://downloadt.advantech.com/download/downloadsr.aspx?File_Id=1-1NHAMZX

Any help would be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a thread that demonstrated the way multi thread works to solve this issue. I tried it myself and it works. It's a little different as a few parts of the code have depreciated. Here is the link to the solution:
[How to stop a warning dialog from halting execution of a Python program that's controlling it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774506/how-to-stop-a-warning-dialog-from-halting-execution-of-a-python-program-thats-c)

Here are the edits I made to solve the problem:

```
def is_admin():
    try:
        return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin()
    except:
        return False

if is_admin():

    def __init__(self, window_name, quit_event):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.quit_event = quit_event
        self.window_name = window_name

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                handles = windows.find_windows(title=self.window_name)
            except windows.WindowNotFoundError:
                pass 
            else: 
                for hwnd in handles:
                    app = Application()
                    app.connect(handle=hwnd)
                    popup = app[self.window_name]
                    popup.close()
            if self.quit_event.is_set():
                break
            time.sleep(1) 

    quit_event = threading.Event()
    mythread = ClearPopupThread('Information', quit_event)
    mythread.start()
    application = Application(backend="uia").start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Advantech\\AdamApax.NET Utility\\Program\\AdamNET.exe")
    time.sleep(2)
    win = application['Advantech Adam/Apax .NET Utility (Win32) Version 2.05.11 (B19)']
    win.menu_select("Setup->Refresh Serial and Ethernet")
    quit_event.set()

else:
    ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, __file__, None, 1)
```

The best thing is this solution works for every other dialog that halts the main script from working & I could use them to do different actions like clicking buttons, inserting values, by adding more multi threads.