# How I do implement multithread in my web scraper?

Tags: python, multithreading, beautifulsoup

I am currently working on a project that requires me to extract data from hundreds of pages. However, I notice that the whole extraction is taking too long since the scraper has to process around 800+ pages. I have read about multiprocessing which I believe it can speed things up but I don't really know how to integrate it to my current code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time

final_data = []

for i in range(1,8271,10):
    url = (f'https://www.fca.org.uk/news/search-results?np_category=warnings&start={i}')
    req = requests.get(url)
    start = time.process_time()
    page_html = req.content
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "lxml")
    data = page_soup.find_all('li', class_='search-item')
    print(f'Processing {url}')

    for x in data:
        list = {}
        list['name'] = x.find('a','search-item__clickthrough').text.strip()
        try:
            list['published_date']=x.find('span','meta-item published-date').text
        except:
            list['published_date'] = 'None'
        list['modified_date']=x.find('span','meta-item modified-date').text

        final_data.append(list)

df = pd.DataFrame(final_data)
TodaysDate = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
csvfilename = TodaysDate + "_FCA Macro.csv"
df.to_csv(csvfilename, encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

Comment: Are you sure that you really need multi-processing and not just multi-threading? The latter could be simpler to implement. And using Pandas only to write a csv file is a bit overkill: the csv module should be enough.

Comment: Multithreading should be adequate for you. Here is a question I asked in the past which made me discover multi threading -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/58163751/12128167

Comment: did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
import threading

final_data = []

def scrape(i):
    url = (f'https://www.fca.org.uk/news/search-results?np_category=warnings&start={i}')
    req = requests.get(url)
    start = time.process_time()
    page_html = req.content
    page_soup = soup(page_html, "lxml")
    data = page_soup.find_all('li', class_='search-item')
    print(f'Processing {url}')

    for x in data:
        list = {}
        list['name'] = x.find('a','search-item__clickthrough').text.strip()
        try:
            list['published_date']=x.find('span','meta-item published-date').text
        except:
            list['published_date'] = 'None'
        list['modified_date']=x.find('span','meta-item modified-date').text

        final_data.append(list)
        

for i in range(1,8271,10):
    threading.Thread(target=scrape, args=(i,)).start()


df = pd.DataFrame(final_data)
TodaysDate = time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
csvfilename = TodaysDate + "_FCA Macro.csv"
df.to_csv(csvfilename, encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

See https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/ for more documentation.

Just use a for loop to create new threads, and pass in `i` for each new thread created. `.start()` is needed to start the thread.

Comment: Thanks for helping me on this issue. I have tried to run the code and the multithreaded is working fine, however, I am not getting the full data using multithread. I am trying to fix the bug.

Comment: Do you think the issue has to do with data races?

Comment: what's data races?